# How to read a csv into pyspark without a java heap memory error

Tags: java-8, pyspark, heap-memory, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a csv into pyspark console with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark
sql_c = SQLContext(sc)
df = sql_c.read.csv('join_rows_no_prepended_new_line.csv')
```

However, I get a very long error about memory usage while I have 144gb free. Additionally, the memory error happens immediately upon running the above code so I not think it is actually a memory error. I've have java 1.8 installed, spark 2.4.0, and python 3.6. I also have scala installed, but I haven't dug into it yet. I do not have hadoop installed (Do I need it?)

To remedy the error I've tried to increase java's heap size, but that hasn't changed the error yet. I've run pyspark with these options set and get the same result `pyspark --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g`

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2019-01-29 23:31:22 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
2019-01-29 23:31:22 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler:91 - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
2019-01-29 23:31:22 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)

2019-01-29 23:31:22 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 472, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2057)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2046)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.append(Text.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
```

Comment: In which mode you are running Pyspark script? Check if it running in cluster mode or not. Post command how you are running spark script?

Comment: Thanks. I am running spark from terminal with the command `pyspark`. I then just type the commands I have.

Comment: How large is your csv? I take it from the conext that it is also not partitioned i.e. it is 1 (potentially large?) file?

Comment: @ags29 You are right, the file is ~65 GB. However the error occurs in approximately 5 seconds of running the last line ie not enough time for even 1 gb to be loaded into memory (I think).

Comment: ok I see, I think you should try splitting the file into a large number of smaller chunks because looking at your executor memory allocation there is no way you could load a single csv of that size without it failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue may be from the way you are submitting your job:

`pyspark --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g`

If the file is, as you say, 65GB, the above submission tells spark to only use 2GB of available memory.

Try ramping the `--driver-memory` parameter to be slightly larger than the size of your .csv file.

e.g `--driver-memory 70G`

To explain why this is necessary:

Without a cluster with a distributed file system, your entire data set sits on your local drive. Spark allows you to split jobs up in an optimised way across a cluster - but without it linked to said cluster of separate machines all of your data will be loaded into your driver's memory. Thus, even though you have higher parallelism here, you need to allow the job to take up as much, or more space than your input file.

**Edit - To answer your questions in the comments:**

There's a few concepts that is core to understanding when you need a full 65G allocated to the driver for a Spark job and when it isn't necessary.

First, Spark runs on a [JVM (Java Virtual Machine)](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3272244/core-java/what-is-the-jvm-introducing-the-java-virtual-machine.html) - a place where the code actually executes. The JVM contains a "Heap Space" which can be understood as how much memory the virtual machine has and may use. In the above scenario, you do not have a cluster of separate machines and your data is not distributed across them so you need to provide the underlying JVM enough memory to hold your data, perhaps even more so if you intend to perform any actions that increase the size of your data in any way.

Now, Spark itself is a framework that allows you to compute computationally expensive tasks in a parallel and optimised fashion but it shows its full potential when you have a distributed file system like [HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System).](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current1/hdfs_design.html)

When storing data in HDFS, you send pieces of it across every machine and Spark allows you to operate on the data stored in this "chunked" way, where every individual executor, on every machine in your cluster, performs your specific operation on a small chunk. Here is the catch though, if you ever wish to "action" your data (I.E collect, show, count) you need to pull the resulting data set all into one place again - which is what we call the driver.

This gives rise to two scenarios:

1. The resulting data, after all operations, is small and thus does not need a full 65GB within the driver. A good example of this is if you had to do an aggregation on the original data and slim the data down from GB to MB.
2. The data is as large, or even bigger than the original which means you need to still provide enough driver memory to hold all of it.

There is quite a lot to understand and play around with in Spark - I highly recommend taking some time to read about how it works and what it can do for you. [Here is also a link to a tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-tutorial/) which can take you through each piece of terminology

Comment: Awesome this works! Will a file's size be representative of its memory required? ie will a 65gb file take 65gb in ram? what about in java heap? I'm totally new to spark.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you! I'll edit my answer above to explain what I can as the comment box won't have enough characters.

Comment: Edited, please let me know if this helps you or if there are some pieces that are still unclear.