# Read CSV file on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am started working with `Spark` and found out one problem.
I tried reading `CSV` file using the below code:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/home/oybek/Serverspace/Serverspace/Athletes.csv")
df.show(5)
```

`Error`:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.csv.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I am working in `Linux Ubuntu, VirtualBox:~/Serverspace`.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/A5rmX7aozRYB , https://prnt.sc/fYI2R6Nht73q , https://prnt.sc/fcEAABSiu_iJ

Comment: Can you add it as a code in the post itself?

Comment: can not to add code in post. here is the link to the code - https://pastebin.com/3YqwwnxF

Comment: How much is the file size which you are trying to read?

Comment: 398 KB, 3 columns 11,000 lines

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431395/how-to-read-a-csv-into-pyspark-without-a-java-heap-memory-error

Comment: Have answered you. Check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the `driver` memory by creating a `spark session` variable like below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g") \
    .appName('read-csv') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: thanks a lot! =) I will answer if it helped later

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Please accept and upvote the answer by clicking on the Tick sign of the answer.

Comment: I want to note that the problem was that I archived the file. Then I opened the file not from the archive and it was considered correctly.