# pyspark - how read from ADLS using obtained credential

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

### EDITED

I am able to read a file on ADLS Gen 2 using pandas and  InteractiveBrowserCredential()

```
#### abfs read test
# from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
# from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem
import pandas as pd
import yaml
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

with open('conf/local/credentials.yml', 'r') as file:
    creds = yaml.safe_load(file)
storage_account_name = creds['storage_account_name']
tenant_id = creds['tenant_id']
file_system = 'project-data' # container
file_path = "myfile.txt.gz"

# authenticating
credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list()) # launches interactive window
print(subscription.subscription_id)
print(subscription.tenant_id) 

dir(credential)
credential._client_id
credential._authority
credential._tenant_id
### authentication successful
```

Now, reading with pandas succeeds with the correct parameters

```
# reading pandas
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
    "https", storage_account_name), credential=credential)

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system)
file_client = file_system_client.get_file_client(file_path)

abfs = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name=storage_account_name, credential=credential)
with abfs.open(f"{file_system}/{file_path}", "rb") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, compression="gzip", sep="\t", header=None, encoding="latin1") # OK******
```

My question is, how to do exactly the same - that is, using the already-obtained `credential` object, but with spark?

```
ff = abfs.open(f"{file_system}/{file_path}", "rb")
spark.read.format("csv").load(ff.full_name)
```

gives

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: abfs://project-data/myfile.txt.gz has invalid authority.
```

and

```
file=f"abfss://project-data@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{file_path}"
xx = spark.read.format("csv").load(file)

# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.load.
# : Failure to initialize configuration
```

Comment: Can you check if this helps you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243630/read-csv-file-on-spark

Comment: hi, no it doesn't

Comment: correct me if I am wrong so you are trying to read data from ADLS using pyspark in databricks?

Comment: no, i'm trying to read from a dev VM on azure

Answer (score 1):

For Spark, you need to pass the file paths to the load function like below to read files from the storage account:

`<protocol>://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>`

Protocol will be either `abfss` or `wasbs`.

For authorization, one of the following should be configured:

- [Azure service principal](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html#0-language-Azure%C2%A0service%C2%A0principal)
- [SAS tokens](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html#0-language-SAS%C2%A0tokens)
- [Account key](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html#0-language-Account%C2%A0key)

To use the above protocols, you also need some packages like [hadoop-azure](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure) and [azure-storage](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage) when using an Azure VM basic environment.

However, you are passing a path like:

```py
abfs://project-data/myfile.txt.gz
```

which is supported in `adlfs` only.

You can try one of the following ways:

1. Copy the data you read in `ff` to a local file and load it.

```py
with abfs.open(f"{file_system}/{file_path}", "r") as f:
    with open("/tmp_folder/tmp.csv",'w') as f2:
        f2.write(f.read())
        
spark.read.csv("/tmp_folder/tmp.csv").show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------------------+------+----+-----+-----+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
|PassengerId|Survived|Pclass|                Name|   Sex| Age|SibSp|Parch|          Ticket|   Fare|Cabin|Embarked|
+-----------+--------+------+--------------------+------+----+-----+-----+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
|          1|       0|     3|Braund, Mr. Owen ...|  male|  22|    1|    0|       A/5 21171|   7.25| NULL|       S|
|          2|       1|     1|Cumings, Mrs. Joh...|female|  38|    1|    0|        PC 17599|71.2833|  C85|       C|
|          3|       1|     3|Heikkinen, Miss. ...|female|  26|    0|    0|STON/O2. 3101282|  7.925| NULL|       S|
|          4|       1|     1|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja...|female|  35|    1|    0|          113803|   53.1| C123|       S|
|          5|       0|     3|Allen, Mr. Willia...|  male|  35|    0|    0|          373450|   8.05| NULL|       S|
```

2. If you already have the `adlfs` package, you can directly read it in pandas and convert it to a Spark DataFrame.

```py
storage_options = {'account_name':'jadls2','account_key': key}
#storage_options={'tenant_id': TENANT_ID, 'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET}
#path='abfs://{CONTAINER}/{FOLDER}/*.csv'
ddf = pd.read_csv('abfs://data/pdf/titanic.csv', storage_options=storage_options)
spark.createDataFrame(ddf).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------------------+------+----+-----+-----+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
|PassengerId|Survived|Pclass|                Name|   Sex| Age|SibSp|Parch|          Ticket|   Fare|Cabin|Embarked|
+-----------+--------+------+--------------------+------+----+-----+-----+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
|          1|       0|     3|Braund, Mr. Owen ...|  male|22.0|    1|    0|       A/5 21171|   7.25| NULL|       S|
|          2|       1|     1|Cumings, Mrs. Joh...|female|38.0|    1|    0|        PC 17599|71.2833|  C85|       C|
|          3|       1|     3|Heikkinen, Miss. ...|female|26.0|    0|    0|STON/O2. 3101282|  7.925| NULL|       S|
|          4|       1|     1|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja...|female|35.0|    1|    0|          113803|   53.1| C123|       S|
|          5|       0|     3|Allen, Mr. Willia...|  male|35.0|    0|    0|          373450|   8.05| NULL|       S|
|          6|       0|     3|    Moran, Mr. James|  male|NULL|    0|    0|          330877| 8.4583| NULL|       Q|
|          7|       0|     1|McCarthy, Mr. Tim...|  male|54.0|    0|    0|           17463|51.8625|  E46|       S|
|          8|       0|     3|Palsson, Master. ...|  male| 2.0|    3|    1|          349909| 21.075| NULL|       S|
|          9|       1|     3|Johnson, Mrs. Osc...|female|27.0|    0|    2|          347742|11.1333| NULL|       S|
```

You can learn more about `adlfs` [here](https://pypi.org/project/adlfs/).